# Meta tag viewport makes the entire page disappear on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, mobile

On this [WordPress site](http://cardioline.it) my client is using a paid WP theme (Fortis7). I had to make several fixes and changes to the default CSS and JS code by adding my separate CSS and JS files to the theme's flow. After noticing that pages turned blank when the meta tag viewport is present (default), I removed all my custom code, thus switching back to the original, which is responsive by design. Nada. Zippo. When the meta tag is on, pages are blank. Any ideas/suggestions/hints?

ps: the HTTP errors you will see in the console don't cause the problem. I've already tested this.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you use this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style.css, Find this line and change width to 100% :

@media (max-width: 600px){body { width: "??";}}

Comment: That's incredible! A container's width set to 1246px when the global viewport's width is 600px... Thanks. I should sue the theme's author. ;-)

Comment: Mark as Yes to my Answer, if you think its correct.